# Saving a rendered file with a audio track on it

Tags: animation

Hi everyone i am just needing some help on my animation i have made. i have rendered it as an animation and added a audio file on top of it but i don't know how to save it as a mp 4 file with the sound on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm showing you my set up.

I select FFmpeg Video RGB.

Container: MPEG-4.

Codec: H.264.

Audio Codec: MP3.

See the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hey buddy you can do it in render tab right side panel. Just. Look for ouput section in this tab you will find Output format sect mp4 as your preference then render . You are done.

Answer (score 0):

## Output Properties

In order to export an animation with audio, you need to change *how* your blender file will output its animation data!

Let's take a quick look at how to output audio in Blender 3.0.

Below is my video file, with my video and audio tracks. Let's navigate to the "Output Properties" tab (Icon outlined in red, which *looks like a small printer*)

[image]

Here, we can manage many of our output settings! Let's take a closer look.

Below, we see an image of the *Output Panel.* If we look closely at the Output panel, we'll see almost everything we need to know about our export:

[image]

The *Output Path* tells your computer *where* to export your animation. (if you give your computer the path to your 'pictures' folder, then it will show up in your pictures folder! And so on.)

The *File Format* tells your computer *how* to export your animation! (Specifically, in what format to export!) Let's look here, to get to the next step.

Currently, our animation is set to export as a sequence of PNG's! This is also known as a flip-book. (I don't know if you've ever seen a flip-book animation before, but unless you plan to make audio by *flapping your lips together*, you need to choose a different method of exporting!) Let's change our animation from a flip-book (PNG) to an MPEG, which can store audio data!

Click on the *"File Format"* box, and select the option that reads *"FFmpeg Video".*
[image]

A new option titled "Encoding" will appear! Click on it.

[image]

The *Container* for your Audio will allow certain programs to read and play your audio without running into trouble! The *Codec* will control the quality of your audio. Each situation is different - But I would *recommend* using the settings below, outlined in red, as they are *versatile*, and are my personal choice:

[image: (Container: MPEG-4) (Audio Codec: AC3) (OPTIONAL Output Quality: Perceptually Lossless)]

*(Container: MPEG-4) (Audio Codec: AC3)
(OPTIONAL, Output Quality: Perceptually Lossless)*

Finally, you are ready to render your animation! To render your full animation, press  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  +  <kbd>F12</kbd> , or navigate to the *Render* header window *(at the top of the .blend file)* and click to render your animation! (Shown below.)

[image]

## Bonus - PNG Rendering - Render Like the Pros

So, if PNG / Flipbooks are so useless, then why are they an option?

Simply put, *it's because they're actually the better option!*

Rendering large animations (Animations that take more than 24 hours) is *very dangerous* when using the above method alone! Renders can have *all kinds of issues,* including crashes, visual errors, frame-skipping, on and on!

When an MPEG render crashes, it cannot usually be recovered, as the data file is typically corrupted by nature of the crash.

*However*, when a PNG render crashes, you only lose *one frame* of your render! *(And that's not even the half of it!)*

Rendering each frame allows for perfect control over *each individual portion* of the render! Have a crashed render? No problem! Render from the last finished frame. Have a render with a visual error? Go to the last working frame, and render from there! Have a render with frame skipping? Sure, you betcha - I'll render *just* the missing frames!

The possibilities are, quite literally, next to endless!

"But, now we're back to the same issue as before! How do I put audio on a flip-book render?"

Actually, it's very simple - and it involves a *second render* where you re-compile your rendered flipbook into an MPEG! (The process takes only a few moments, up to a few hours, and is much less risky!) Here's a video explaining how to render *PNG Sequences* (the technical term for a "flip-book.")

Here is the Link, pasted below:

https://youtu.be/Bgab9VC_laQ

Let me know if you need anything!

*Good luck, and Happy Blending!*